# True or False Test Grader using Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Heads up yes this is homework but I have almost all of it completed I just need help with calculating scores method  and the output method. Im not asking for someone to complete it I just need some help.

One of your professors needs help grading a True/False test. The students’ IDs and test answers are stored in a file. The first entry in the file contains the answers to the test in the following form:

TFFTFFTTTTFFTFTFTFTT

The second entry in the file is an integer that is the total number of students in the file.

Every other entry in the file is the student’s ID, followed by a blank, followed by the student’s response. For example, the entry:

ABC54301 TFTFTFTT TFTFTFFTTFT

indicates that the student’s ID is ABC54301 and the answer to question 1 is True, the answer to question 2 is False, and so on. This student did not answer question 9. Each blank answer should be replaced with an S (to indicate a skipped question). The exam has 20 questions.

Each correct answer is awarded two points, each wrong answer gets -1 point, and no answer gets 0 points. Write a program that processes the test data. The first line of each student’s output should be the student’s ID, followed by the answers, followed by the test score, followed by the test grade. The second line should contain an X under each of the answers the student missed.

Assume the following grade scale: 90% - 100%, A; 80% - 89.99%, B; 70% - 79.99%, C; 60% - 69.99%, D; and 0% - 59.99%, F.

The data from the input file must be input all at once and stored in a single variable. The data must be output all at once from a single variable.  You MUST use multiple methods in your program.  It is up to you how many to create, but there is a minimum amount that you should have and you will be counted off for putting too much code in your main method.

Example Input:

ABC54301 TFTFTFTT TFTFTFFTTFT

Example Output:
ABC54301 TFTFTFTTSTFTFTFFTTFT 77.5% C
         XXX  X XXXX XX

Heres all of my code so far I need help with 2 Methods and that's about it Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestGrader
{
  public static Scanner inFile;
  public static PrintWriter outFile;

  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
  {
    inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("GradesIn.dat"));
    outFile = new PrintWriter("GradesOut.dat");

    String testAnswers = inFile.next();

    int numberOfStudents = inFile.nextInt();
    double[] testScores = new double[numberOfStudents];

    String[][] studentTests = new String[numberOfStudents][2];
    StringBuilder[][] studentResults = new StringBuilder[numberOfStudents][2];    

    initializeResults(studentResults);
    getData(studentTests);
    gradeTests(studentTests, studentResults, testAnswers, testScores);    
    outputData(studentTests, studentResults, testScores);

    outFile.close();
    inFile.close();
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Method Name: initializeResults
  // Called By:   main()
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public static void initializeResults(StringBuilder[][] studentResults)
  {
    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < studentResults.length; rowIndex++)
    {
      for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex < studentResults[rowIndex].length; colIndex++)
      {
        if(colIndex == 0)
        {
          studentResults[rowIndex][colIndex] = new StringBuilder("        ");
        }
        else
        {
          studentResults[rowIndex][colIndex] = new StringBuilder("                    ");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Method Name: getData
  // Called By:   main()
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public static void getData(String[][] studentTests)
  {    
    String[] temp = new String[studentTests.length];

    inFile.nextLine();

    for(int index = 0; index < (temp.length); index++)
    {
      temp[index] = inFile.nextLine();
    }

    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < studentTests.length; rowIndex++)
    {      
        studentTests[rowIndex][0] = temp[rowIndex].substring(0,8);
    }

    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < studentTests.length; rowIndex++)
    {      
        studentTests[rowIndex][1] = temp[rowIndex].substring(9, 29);
    }
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Method Name: gradeTests
  // Called By:   main()
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public static void gradeTests(String[][] studentTests, StringBuilder[][] studentResults, String testAnswers, double[] testScores)
  {    

  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Method Name: outputData
  // Called By:   main()
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public static void outputData(String[][] studentTests, StringBuilder[][] studentResults, double[] testScores)
  {

  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Method Name:  calculateLetterGrade
  // Called By:    outputData()
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public static String calculateLetterGrade(double testScore)
  {
    String letterGrade = "";

      if((testScore / 40 * 100) < 60.0)
      {
        letterGrade = "F";
      }
      else if((testScore / 40 * 100) < 70.0)
      {
        letterGrade = "D";
      }
      else if((testScore / 40 * 100) < 80.0)
      {
        letterGrade = "C";
      }
      else if((testScore / 40 * 100) < 90.0)
      {
        letterGrade = "B";
      }
      else
      {
        letterGrade = "A";
      }

      return letterGrade;
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: This is not a website where you paste your code and ask for "help". You need to formulate an actual question, posting only the relevant code.

Comment: The two methods that are called outputData and gradeTest. I just need like a starting point for me to start on it Like the gradeTest method is the method that actualy grades the students tests and the outputData method I'm guessing sends the data to the OutputFile.dat

Comment: Count the T and F, calculate the grade. Why do you have a 2D-StringBuilder array? You already have a method signature, what did you think about that? Why did you choose those parameters?

Comment: This is how my instructor told us to do it. Im just following his instructions. Sorry

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### " " -> "S"

First try to get rid of the spaces while getting data, makes it easier for later processing (and avoids putting that behaviour into the grading method).

```
studentTests[rowIndex][1] = temp[rowIndex].substring(9, 29).replace(" ", "S");
```

Additionally you should take care for the case that the last (and the second last, and n-2, n-3, all) question got unanswered, your linebreak will then be earlier. But I leave that to you.

### Grading

Then go to your gradeTests method and well... just compare the answer to the results and count according to the formula you were given.

```
for(int i = 0; i < studentTests.length; ++i) {
    int score = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < result.length(); ++j) {
        if(studentTests[i][1].charAt(j) == testAnswers.charAt(j)) {
            ++score;
        } else if(studentTests[i][1].charAt(j) != 'S') {
            --score;
        }
    }
    testScores[i] = score;
}
```

Here you have to figure out what you need the creepy StringBuilders for yourself. I give you a hint: It seems to have something to do with the `X`s.

### Output

Format your results according to the output.
You already have a student number in `studentTests[row][0]`, you have the individual answers in `studentTests[row][1]`, you have the score in points in `testScores[row]`, and you should have the String with Xs if you finished your grading method correctly, somewhere in `studentResults`. Now get the percentage score and the letter grade, put everything together and you are done.

Good luck

Comment: I don't understand your down votes - I didn't solve it completely but gave some hints. That answers "I need help with 2 Methods" from the question and "I just need like a starting point" from the comments and also doesn't solve it completely. How can I improve?